# Is the iBooks app sandboxed on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, security, ibook

I would like to know if ibooks app on Mavericks is sandboxed.

I might read some unsecure ebooks (from internet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is sandboxed.

[image: iBooks as shown in Activity Monitor with "Sandbox" == "Yes"]

…so you should be fine to read books out of the Internet.

Comment: Thanks i know where to look now if i want to know about any other app